# Storing Sensitive Data

Tags: mysql, security, filesystems

Suppose I want to store terminalCode, merchantCode, pin, user, pass ... for connecting to a web service should i store them in a config file on the system out of web root or store them in a separate database table with special privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Storing them in a file outside of your webroot is very safe as long as you ensure access to your cPanel FTP etc is well protected with a good password.

Or alternitavely in an example of using PHP, you can just store the credentials for access to the database in PHP variables in a PHP include file outside of your webroot, and reference it in any PHP files that will access the database.  Then you can make your usernames and passwords super long and very hard to crack, and you only have to type them in once (in the include file).

Comment: If you have a FTP-server running, it can't be well-protected…

Comment: @feeela Sure it can, as long as no accounts have access to the webroot. I do this so that I can transfer files via FTP, and then move them using my cPanel or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your webserver settings, there could be easier methods; for example using a dotfile (e.g. `.config`) which are hidden by the Apache server in the default configuration.